# Control Panel theme that looks like Wordpress

Tags: control-panel, themes, cp-themes

I think EE's Control Panel is super simple and intuitive. Granted, I have been using it for over 3 years now, so I am comfortable in it. However, I have had several clients over the years express that they are more comfortable in the Wordpress Backend.

I was wondering, is there any Control Panel theme available that makes the EE Control Panel look and behave similar to Wordpress' backend? (Nav on the left, similar nav organization, publish page layout, etc).

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I was able to accomplish most of what I wanted by modifying the control panel CSS. Basically, just to get the top nav down along the left. 
[image: Wordpressy EE Screenshot]

It's not everything I wanted, but it's a start. Basically, I just made a copy of `/themes/cp_themes/default/` and called it `/themes/cp_themes/wordpressy/` and added the following CSS to `global.css`:

```
body {
    background-color: #27343C;
}
#branding {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#mainMenu {
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#navigationTabs {
    margin: 0px;
}
#navigationTabs li:last-child{
    width:100%;
}
#navigationTabs li,
#navigationTabs li li {
    float: none;
}
#mainWrapper {
    float: right;
    width: 85%;
}
```

I would like to be able to split the main "Content" menu item into individual menu items for each Channel, with maybe "Add New" and "View All" sub items... maybe I could do that with some clever jQuery?

And my reasoning again, for those who think this is a pointless endeavor, is just to break down some imaginary barriers that some clients of mine seem to have when switching to a new CMS.

Comment: You really want to screw up the EE CMS to Wordpress CMS... Is doomsday comming.....??? ;)

Comment: I really don't think it's that drastic of a difference, really. Basically, I think it would just help soothe clients that are comfortable with Wordpress. If the nav was down the left side, and we could have a nav item for each channel there too, rather than having them under 'Content'....  now I'm wondering if I could just do it with some CSS tweaks and jQuery..

Comment: Custom nav items pointed to whatever you like is also possible with Zoo Flexible Admin - see my answer below and check out the add-on for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend giving [Zoo Flexible Admin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin) a whirl.  It allows you to create a custom menu in the control panel per member group - and that is a pretty powerful thing when it comes to reorganizing the menus in the control panel, labelling them in a manner that makes sense for your client and stripping out anything they really don't need to see or even have access to. You can greatly simplify the control panel and achieve a much more streamlined experience for your site admins with it.  I highly recommend it.  And of course within the publish page itself, EE's native publish layouts give you the ability to reorganize the publish screen itself - not hugely, but certainly enough to improve the admin experience there as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the available CP themes at http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/filter?t=cpt - but in the end EE and WP are different applications, think about content differently, and hence require different architectures in the Control Panel.